# ¿Qué nombres reciben los niños de los albergues?

Tags: coloquialismos, solicitud-de-término

Albergues, hospicios o internados hay de varios tipos: sitios donde se practica la educación básica, donde hay dormitorios y donde los niños no salen hasta su adolescencia o mayoría de edad, algunos porque fueron abandonados.

Hay otros sitios de asistencia social donde los padres dejan (a veces voluntariamente y otras obligados por el gobierno) a los hijos todos los días de la semana (o durante meses) porque sus hogares no cuentan con las condiciones o por problemas de violencia.

A los niños que crecen en estos lugares, en México, se les llama despectivamente "`pelón de hospicio`", porque los rapan para evitar problemas de piojos. La misma frase se usa para referirse a las personas en la vida cotidiana, por ejemplo cuando alguien come muy rápido se le dice `"comes como pelón de hospicio".`

Sé que en Inglaterra hay un dicho particular. Quisiera saber si en América Latina, Alemania, España u otros sitios tienen un nombre similar.

Ese nombre puede ser tan local como deba ser, por ejemplo, si en una ciudad que conozcan existe un centro llamado **El arbolito** podrían referirse a los niños problemáticos como *seguro son niños del Arbolito*.

Comment: Nótese que el uso de [_albergue_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1XOT8ne) para designar _Casa destinada a la crianza y refugio de niños huérfanos o desamparados_ está marcado por la DRAE como en desuso y, en general, se entiende más como el lugar donde uno paga por dormir alguna noche.

Comment: En Chile se les dice _internos_, pero es una palabra demasiado general como para ofrecerla de respuesta. Para precisar diríamos _internos del SENAME_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una pregunta que, efectivamente, puede tener multitud de respuestas posibles según la región. Aquí en España hay un colegio de internados muy famoso (al menos en la zona de Andalucía) que se llama [Campillos](http://colegiocampillos.com/). Ellos mismos lo dicen en su artículo "[El internado más famoso de España](http://colegiocampillos.com/el-internado-mas-famoso-de-espana/)":

> «¡Te voy a mandar interno a Campillos!» Era una de las frases más amenazadoras que podía dedicar un padre a su hijo hace algunos años.

Y de hecho, cuando yo estudiaba en el colegio conocí a niños que acabaron yendo a Campillos internados. Así que frases que te podrían servir en el caso de España podrían ser del tipo "ese es de Campillos fijo" o "va a acabar en Campillos". Nótese en todo caso que en este caso la expresión solo aplicaría para niños problemáticos, pero no para los abandonados.

Answer (score 4):

Existen palabras para referirse a los niños criados en este tipo de establecimientos, derivadas de los nombres que reciben los mismos. Así, de *hospicio* tenemos [hospiciano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KhNlzoQ), y de *inclusa*, [inclusero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LFSvW6y).

Estas palabras se pueden considerar despectivas; pero no por la intención de las palabras en sí, sino por la discriminación que han venido sufriendo estos niños. En realidad, son palabras neutras: hay un torero, por ejemplo, que usa como nombre artístico [El Inclusero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorio_T%C3%A9bar_P%C3%A9rez) por haberse criado en uno de estos lugares.

Comment: Curiosa la etimología de "[inclusa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LFPOCSo)": De Nuestra Señora de la _Inclusa_, imagen de la Virgen traída en el siglo XVI de la isla _L'Écluse_, en Holanda, y colocada en la casa de expósitos de Madrid.